# Error al añadir entero a una lista: TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Tags: python

Estoy trabajando sobre un fichero cuyas columnas son números en formato `str`, tengo que meter los números (con tipo `int`) de una columna en una lista. Para ello tengo la siguiente función:

```
def resumen_datos(identificador_fichero="monica.csv",identificador_variable="outcome"):
    datos_variable_numerica=list()

    with open("monica.csv","r") as f:
        variables=f.readline()
        variables=variables.replace('"','')
        variables=variables.rstrip('\n')
        variables=variables.split(",")

        if identificador_variable not in variables:
            print ('la variable introducida no se encuentra en el fichero')
            return False
        if identificador_variable in variables:
            posicion_variable=variables.index(identificador_variable)
            #print (posicion_variable)
        for line in f:
            line=line.replace('"','')
            line=line.rstrip('\n')
            line=line.split(",")
            datos_variable=int(line[posicion_variable])
            datos_variable_numerica+=datos_variable
```

Pero al llamarla obtengo el siguiente error:

> TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

¿Cómo puedo hacer para meter en una lista los números de una columna?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que intentas concatenar una lista (`datos_variable_numerica`) con un entero (`datos_variable`):

```
datos_variable_numerica+=datos_variable
```

Esto causa que se intente iterar sobre `datos_variable` causando la excepción.

Puedes concatenar dos listas (`datos_variable_numerica+=[datos_variable]`) pero es mejor que uses `list.append` en su lugar para evitar crear la lista temporal:

```
datos_variable_numerica.append(datos_variable)
```

---

Otra opción es usar compresión de listas que es más eficiente que `append`:

```
datos_variable_numerica = [int(line.replace('"','').rstrip('\n').split(",")[posicion_variable])
                               for line in  f]
```

Por ejemplo:

```
# Lista para emular el contenido de tu csv
f = ['"4","8","9"\n',
     '"8","6","6"\n',
     '"8","6","1"\n']

pos = 2
columna = [int(line.replace('"','').rstrip('\n').split(",")[pos]) for line in  f]
print(columna)
# [9, 6, 1]
```

---

Si lo deseas puedes usar el módulo [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) que te facilita la tarea de parsear el csv:

- Usando `csv.reader`:

  ```
  import csv


  def resumen_datos(file="monica.csv", identificador="outcome"):
      with open(file) as f:
          reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')

          header = next(reader)
          if identificador in header:
              pos = header.index(identificador)
          else:
              return False

          return [int(row[pos]) for row in reader]
  ```
- Usando `csv.DictReader`:

  ```
  import csv


  def resumen_datos(file="monica.csv", identificador="outcome"):
      with open(file) as f:
          reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')

          if not identificador in reader.fieldnames:
              return False

          return [int(row[identificador]) for row in reader]
  ```

Ambos para un csv:

> col1,col2,outcome
>   "1","2","3"
>   "4","5","6"
>   "7","8","9"

nos retornan:

```
>>> resumen_datos()
[3, 6, 9]
```