# ¿Cómo hacer una regresión en una serie temporal de vectores?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regresión-lineal

Tengo una dataframe que es una serie temporal de vectores:

```
date_block_num  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33
shop_id                                                                                                                                     
0   5578.0  6127.0  3198.73913  2330.217391 2377.111111 2725.673913 2542.73913  2784.244444 2962.933333 2772.630435 2889.088889 3985.695652 2541.282609 2384.5  2402.020833 1970.530612 1995.714286 1988.346939 1825.6  2014.137255 1984.16 2065.807692 2356.9  3375.1  2219.42 1791.446809 1782.913043 1655.893617 1643.068182 1491.023256 1469.465116 1573.309524 1694.023256 1614.909091
1   2947.0  3364.0  3198.73913  2330.217391 2377.111111 2725.673913 2542.73913  2784.244444 2962.933333 2772.630435 2889.088889 3985.695652 2541.282609 2384.5  2402.020833 1970.530612 1995.714286 1988.346939 1825.6  2014.137255 1984.16 2065.807692 2356.9  3375.1  2219.42 1791.446809 1782.913043 1655.893617 1643.068182 1491.023256 1469.465116 1573.309524 1694.023256 1614.909091
2   1146.0  488.0   753.00000   583.000000  553.000000  832.000000  807.00000   875.000000  945.000000  795.000000  862.000000  1322.000000 890.000000  911.0   990.000000  791.000000  910.000000  957.000000  838.0   956.000000  920.00  945.000000  1192.0  1921.0  987.00  907.000000  762.000000  859.000000  843.000000  804.000000  785.000000  942.000000  822.000000  727.000000
...
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quería saber si puedo usar la regresión lineal múltiple para predecir el resultado del próximo mes, el 34.

De hecho, me doy cuenta de que tengo problemas para minimizar el error estocástico. Estoy comparando estos valores:

```
[7.02621560e+08 6.46755686e+08 8.65277293e+08 4.80427731e+08
 4.75597320e+08 6.31822980e+08 5.49750805e+08 6.34290473e+08
 7.24865565e+08 6.41236197e+08 6.94704189e+08 1.37244375e+09
 5.59026765e+08 4.73088942e+08 4.89861510e+08 3.51994197e+08
 3.36726115e+08 3.48503942e+08 2.86840266e+08 3.70450158e+08
 3.43496438e+08 3.87950359e+08 4.89900086e+08 1.04003940e+09
 4.61547311e+08 2.78160154e+08 2.79012580e+08 2.56612063e+08
 2.33094005e+08 1.91314690e+08 1.77093854e+08 1.92028120e+08
 2.75592392e+08 2.30760424e+08] inf
```

Y por lo tanto, tengo este error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-53-f6846fe663d3> in <module>()
     79                                   out.values,
     80                                   theta,
---> 81                                   0.001)
     82 
     83 print("alpha: ", alpha, "beta: ", beta)

<ipython-input-53-f6846fe663d3> in minimize_stochastic(target_fn, gradient_fn, x, y, theta_0, alpha_0)
     54     # print("value: ", value)
     55     print(value, min_value)
---> 56     if value < min_value:
     57       # if we've found a new minimum, remember it
     58       # and go back to the original step size

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Aquí está el algoritmo:

```
import random

def predict(alpha, beta, x_i):
  return alpha+ beta * x_i

def error(alpha, beta, x_i, y_i):
  """the error from predicting beta * x_i + alpha
  when the actual value is y_i"""
  return y_i - predict(alpha, beta, x_i)

def sum_of_squarred_errors(alpha, beta, x, y):
  return sum(errors(alpha, beta, x_i, y_i)**2
             for x_i, y_i in zip(x,y))
  
def correlation(x,y):
  stdev_x = standard_deviation(x)
  stdev_y = standard_deviation(y)
  if stdev_x > 0 and stdev_y >0:
    return covariance(x,y)/ stdev_x/ stdev_y
  else:
    return 0

def squared_error(x_i, y_i, theta):
  alpha, beta = theta
  return error(alpha, beta, x_i, y_i) ** 2

def squared_error_gradient(x_i, y_i, theta):
  alpha, beta = theta
  return [-2 * error(alpha, beta, x_i, y_i),
          -2 * error(alpha, beta, x_i, y_i) * x_i]

def in_random_order(data):
  """generator that returns the elements if data in random order"""
  indexes = [i for i, _ in enumerate(data)] # create a list of indexes
  random.shuffle(indexes) # suffle them
  for i in indexes:
    yield data[i]

def scalar_multiply(c, v):
    """c is a number, v is a vector"""
    return [c*v_i for v_i in v]

def minimize_stochastic(target_fn, gradient_fn, x,y, theta_0, alpha_0=0.01):
  print("x: ", x, "\ny: ",y.tolist())
  data = zip(x,y)
  theta = theta_0  #initial guess
  alpha = alpha_0  # initial step size
  min_theta, min_value = None, float('inf') # the minimum so far
  iterations_with_no_improvment = 0

  # if we ever go 100 iterations with no improvment, stop
  while iterations_with_no_improvment < 100:
    value = sum(target_fn(x_i, y_i, theta) for x_i, y_i in data)
    # print("value: ", value)
    print(value, min_value)
    if value < min_value:
      # if we've found a new minimum, remember it
      # and go back to the original step size
      min_theta, min_value = theta, value
      iterations_with_no_improvment = 0
      alpha = alpha_0
    else:
      # otherwise we're not improving, so try shrinking the step size
      iterations_with_no_improvment +=1
      alpha *=0.9

    # and take a gradient step for each of the data points
    for x_i, y_i in in_random_order(data):
      gradient_i = gradient_fn(x_i, y_i, theta)
      theta = vector_substract(theta, scalar_multiply(alpha, gradient_i))
  return min_theta

# choose random value to start
random.seed(0)
theta = [random.random(), random.random()]

alpha, beta = minimize_stochastic(squared_error,
                                  squared_error_gradient, out.index.values,
                                  out.values,
                                  theta,
                                  0.001)

predict(alpha, beta, 34)
```

Podría crear un vector de -inf que sería del tamaño del otro vector, ¿pero cómo lo calcularía? ¿Comparando la media? Lo intenté, pero me dio la impresión de que el objeto no es iterable:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-60-2644d8e4b178> in <module>()
     82                                   out.values,
     83                                   theta,
---> 84                                   0.001)
     85 
     86 print("alpha: ", alpha, "beta: ", beta)

<ipython-input-60-2644d8e4b178> in minimize_stochastic(target_fn, gradient_fn, x, y, theta_0, alpha_0)
     57     # print("value: ", value)
     58     # print(len(value), len(min_value))
---> 59     if sum(value) < sum(min_value):
     60       # if we've found a new minimum, remember it
     61       # and go back to the original step size

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Error al añadir entero a una lista: TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/128080/error-al-a%c3%b1adir-entero-a-una-lista-typeerror-int-object-is-not-iterable)

Comment: La pregunta menciona dos errores. Uno es "objeto is not iterable; el otro ha sido respondido en [Error al intentar calcular elemento con mayor valor de un array](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/9477/error-al-intentar-calcular-elemento-con-mayor-valor-de-un-array)